# best practices for application logging azure web applications?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, azure-table-storage

I am developing an application using asp.net mvc 3, windows azure. i am looking for suggestions for error logging and application logging.

Comment: Maybe this link to [MSDN:Take Control of Logging and Tracing in Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714589.aspx) can be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the Enterprise library and configure a DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener that writes into your table storage.

You can find some info on the trace listener here:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/

Comment: Hi Michael, is diagnostics can fit for error log(exceptional messages) like log4net, Elmah ? I need to use log info to fix bugs :)

Comment: Hi Ramesh, Yes it can do all of that for you. I would even suggest you look into using Unity from the Enterprise Library as well. This gives you a lot of flexibility to turn on and off logging/tracing on the fly. For example, you could write your own call handler that wraps a try/catch block around all or some controller actions based on the interception configuration if you use DI.